# ESXi 5 - Custom build iscsi or openfiler?

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi

This is for a development environment, NOT a production environment. We have 2 ESXi 5 hosts that is currently using their own local disks for storage. We have a very large Supermicro server that has 16TB of diskspace. We're thinking of either installing Openfiler or installing RH 5 and configuring iSCSI ourselves. What are some of the drawbacks to going the RH route?

I thought I read somewhere that Openfiler doesn't work too well w/ VMware. I'm not sure if this is the case w/ Openfiler 2.99.

Thanks

Comment: lately I've been using NFS vs ISCSI it will give you more control over the datastores.

Comment: I'd try openindiana with zfs,  it too has a live cd.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the hardware I used, but periodically the openfiler would freeze up and required a reboot, about a year ago. However, judging by your needs it is probably adequate. However, the new version could have improved.

RH is simpler to set up for me as I am more familiar with it and can have full control easily. Openfiler has another problem that I did not quite figure out in file permissions and ownership, if you go the nfs route. If you use iscsci however, it is just a block device so it is easier.

So I would say RH if you are a linux guy, and openfiler if you are not, because the latter provides a web gui to configure things very quickly and easily, for those who has no prior linux/bsd experience.

Comment: RH person here as well, one thing I like about OF is that it provides a nice GUI. I like the fact that you could mask the LUN. I wasnt able to figure this out when I had RH setup.

Comment: By the way, OF can run in livecd mode so you can quickly try it out easily without disturbing the server, which can be in RH or whatevere OS, and then only install it if you are satisfied.